# $\textit{Why}$ the cases in 4 $\nmid n^2 - 3?$ (bases cases in modular induction)

Tags: proof-explanation, divisibility

This question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880499/if-n-is-an-integer-then-4-does-not-divide-n2-3). My question is, when we suppose the hypothesis is not true (proof by contradiction), namely that $4 \mid (n^2 - 3)$, we get $n^2 - 3 = 4k$ for some integer $k$ and then we have two cases. But where does the two cases come from? In addition, why does putting them into two cases work to prove the statment? My thought process would be to try to prove this statement by contradiction and somehow figure out a way to produce a contradiction similar to how $\sqrt{2}$ is proved by contradiction. Any help is great!

Let me know if I need to clarify more!

Comment: Good question. I don't have a high level understanding of this. For small numbers (e.g. 4, where there are only 4 conceivable remainders after division by 4) it is just very common for theorems of this type to deal with some or all of the cases by hand (e.g. remainder is 1 or 3 after division by 4, or 0 or 2 after division by 4). There may be other ways to solve the problem, but this kind of "brute force" approach is often very effective.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.  Since the case of even $n$ is obvious, it is natural enough to restrict attention to odd $n$.  But, feel free to try it a different way!  It's often useful to have multiple proofs for a given claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why the cases, and where do the two cases come from? In addition, why does putting them into two cases work to prove the statment?

Since these specific questions were not addressed in prior answers, we explicitly address them here. In this type of induction (by *modular cases*) there are generally *multiple* base cases corresponding to each possible remainder $\bmod n$. Let's bring to the fore the logical essence of matter.

Congruence $\!\bmod 4\,$ is an equivalence relation on $\,\Bbb Z\,$ whose classes *partition* $\,\Bbb Z\,$ into $\,4\,$ cosets (arithmetic progressions) $\,r_i + 4\Bbb Z$, $\,r_i \in \{0,1,2,3\}.\,$ The naturals in each coset have the same order structure as $\Bbb N,\,$ so we can use induction to prove that a statement is true for all elements in the coset. If we prove that for all $4$ cosets ($4$ case analyses) then that suffices as a proof that the statement is true for all naturals since, the union of the cosets $= \Bbb Z \supset \Bbb N$.

Sometimes we can give a single proof that works *uniformly* for all cosets, but generally we may need a (brute force) case analysis, examining each of the $\,n\,$ possible cosets, e.g. when $\,n = 2\,$ this amounts to a proof by *parity*  using two base cases even & odd. A prototypical example, is the [Parity Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15670/242), which shows that an integer coefficient polynomial has no integer roots if it has no roots $\bmod 2$, essentially performing a parity analysis on possible roots, i.e. if it has no even root and no odd root then it has no integer root, e.g. if $\,n\,$ is odd then $\,x^2+x+n\,$ has no integer roots because it is always odd $\,f(0)\equiv 1\equiv f(1)\pmod{\!2}.\,$ The same idea works $\!\bmod n,\,$ i.e. an integer coef polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ has no integer roots if it has no roots $\!\bmod n\,$ i.e. if $\,f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(n-1)\,$ are all $\not\equiv 0.\,$ The OP follows from the special case $\,f(x) = x^2-3,\ n = 4\,$ (the common proof you linked is essentially just a slight optimization of this modular root test).

As in the proof of this root test, in practice said induction in each coset is not usually *explicitly* done because typically we employ other results that help to simplify the matter - so the induction in the cosets actually ends up being hidden somewhere down the line in another theorem or lemma. For example, in the proof of the root test it boils down to $\,n\equiv (n\bmod 2)\in \{0,1\}\,$ by the Division Algorithm (computing the least element (remainder) in each coset is essentially induction in that coset). [Down the line it also implicitly uses (structural) induction in the proof of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (to essentially decompose the polynomial into compositions of sums and products) but this is not the *modular case* induction that we are concerned with here].

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855263/question-about-basis-step-of-strong-induction-proof).

Answer (score 2):

So $n^2\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$. Hence $n^2-3\equiv 1,2\pmod 4$ which is not a multiple of $4$.

Comment: This does not answer either question posed in the OP. They already know the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a proof by contradiction it might *seem* like you don't need two cases (but you actually do).

If $n^2 - 3 = 4k$ then $4k$ is even so $n^2=4k + 3$ is odd.  So $n$ is odd.

SO $n = 2m+1$ for some $m$ and $n^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1= 4(m^2 + m) + 1$.

But $n^2 = 4k + 3$ so $4(m^2 +m) + 1 = 4k +3$.

So $4(m^2+m) - 4k = 2$.

So $4(m^2 + m-k) = 2$ and $2(m^2 + m -k) = 1$.  But $1$ is odd and $2(m^2 + m-k)$ is even.  A contradiction.

In this case that case that $n$ might be even was tacitly dismissed as an impossibility.

But tacitly dismissing as an impossibility *is* a contradiction.  It's just a case that needn't be considered as it was directly proven to be false.

....

And you don't need just two cases. It's that two cases are sufficient.

I could have done it with $10$ cases.

Let $n = 10k + i$ where $i=0,1,2,3,...9$.

And $n^2 - 3 = 4(25k^2 + 5ki) + (i^2 -3)$.

Need to show $4\not\mid i^2 -3$.  And considering the the $10$ cases we see

$i^2 -3 = -3, -2, 1, 6, 13,22, 33,46,61,78$ are none of them divisible by $4$.